# pre-render an R script for each chapter of a quarto book project

Tags: r, bookdown, quarto

I have a bookdown project in R and like to switch to Quarto.
In the bookdown project I have an R script `_common.R` (it includes libraries and various settings and helper functions) to run before the rendering of each chapter (separate qmd file).

How can I implement such a script-file in Quarto?

I tried to set in _quarto.yml:

```
project:
  type: book
  pre-render: _common.R
```

But this will only run the script once before the rendering of the complete book, not before each chapter.
Each chapter seems to be rendered in its own environment so all the settings and scripts from `_common.R` are not available.

A workaround is to include

````
```{r echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
source("_common.R")
```
````

at the top of each .Rmd/.qmd file. Is there a better solution?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to your proposed workaround, you can use a project-specific `.Rprofile` file in your project and call the `source` inside that `.Rprofile`.

**`.Rprofile`**

```
source("_common.R")
```

And in this approach, you don't have to source the `_common.R` file at the start of each chapter qmd files.

Comment: Keep in mind that R will source only one `.Rprofile` file, so you need either explicitly source the user-level `.Rprofile` at the top of your project-level `.Rprofile` with `source("~/.Rprofile")` or you will lose your project-level `.Rprofile` settings.

Comment: Instead of using a {knitr} chunk with `source("_common.R")` using the `include` shortcode  `{{< include _common.qmd >}}` would be a more general Quarto like solution, not restricted to R. See [Includes](https://mine-cetinkaya-rundel.github.io/quarto-tip-a-day/posts/04-include/index.html) and [source() script at start of document](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/3250). But this still has the disadvantage, that you need to paste this include statement inside all your qmd-files.