# sharing data across pages in quarto when loading from source file in R

Tags: rstudio, quarto

I have an `index.qmd` page in quarto that loads a dataset

````
```{r}
test <- TRUE
source(paste0(getwd(),"/loading.R"))
```
````

I have another page `page1.qmd` that needs to use the datasets loaded by the index page

````
```{r}
print(check)
print(test)
```
````

the `loading.R` file contains code to create `check`

```
check <- TRUE
```

Rendering using `quarto render` gives the following error:

```
←[1m←[34m[ 1/20] about.qmd←[39m←[22m
←[1m←[34m[ 2/20] page1.qmd←[39m←[22m
?[31m

processing file: page1.rmarkdown
  |...................................                                   |  50%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
?[31mQuitting from lines 2-7 (page1.rmarkdown)
?[39m?[31mError in print(check) : object 'check' not found
```

It seems that the source load doesn't put things into global memory. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73536041/10858321) may be of help and also you may look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73638836/10858321).